# Ubuntu unrar does not extract dot files

Tags: ubuntu, unrar

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm getting a rar file on my ubuntu server through wget and I do `unrar e -r file.rar` to extract all files. However, files like `.htaccess` are not extracted. I know it is present because when I download it on my PC, winrar shows .htaccess file in rar file.

How do I extract all files from rar with unrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid, but I was just doing `ls` which does not show dot files by default. Doing `ls -a` shows that.